# A Path with Variables

Tags: powershell, variables, path

Not much to explain just watch.

```
$env = '@PROD'
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh:mm:ss"
$LogFile = '"C:/Test/test/test/Log/"+$LogTime+"_Log_"+$env+".log"'
Write-Host $LogFile
```

But the $LogFile isn't right. Output = "C:\Test\test\test\Log\"+$LogTime+"*Log*"+$env+".log"

Comment: Remove the single-quotes `'` that surround the entire thing

Comment: A good reference for how to use quotation marks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're over-complicating things; I'd suggest using string expansion.  Also, `$env` is a bad variable name as it matches the scope modifier name, and colons (`:`) are not valid characters in Windows' file structures.

```
$Environment = '@PROD'
$LogTime = Get-Date -Format 'MM-dd-yyyy_hh.mm.ss'
                              ## Alternatively, ${Environment} for clarity
$LogFile = "C:\Test\test\test\Log\${LogTime}_Log_$Environment.log"

Write-Host $LogFile
```

Comment: Nice catch with `$env`, I'd probably qualify it with `${Environment}` as well for readability

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Good suggestion.  I'd like to take the opportunity here to say you can name your variables whatever you'd like as long as they are surrounded with curly braces after the dollar sign: `${this is a valid variable name :emoji:} = 6` and it also definitively states the beginning/end of a variable name in cases where underscores or the like can be interpreted as part of the name.

Comment: ${} = 'They certainly can'

Comment: @ManuelHedinger If this solved your problem, kindly mark it as the answer for future searchers!